# Naked, I make blue clothing - Riddle

Tags: riddle

> Naked, I make blue clothing that I never wear
>   Clothed, I am cold and shy
>   People sell in shops what I give for free
>   People travel far to receive my gifts.
>   People travel far to avoid my gifts.
>   Many love me and many shun me.
>   No one truly visits me
>   But I am not lonely

**Who or what am I?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the solution:

> The sun

Naked, I make blue clothing that I never wear

> Direct sun light is bleaching clothes

Clothed, I am cold and shy

> Clothed or covered by clouds, the warmth of the sun is not reaching us. It is also shy, because we can't see it.

People sell in shops what I give for free

> Spray tan

People travel far to receive my gifts.

> Holiday in the sun

People travel far to avoid my gifts.

> Escaping the heating sun

Many love me and many shun me.

> The sun is loved by many and hated by others.

No one truly visits me

> No man has been on the sun

But I am not lonely

> Many suns (other stars)

Comment: The sun makes the sky blue ..  the sky is blue clothing the sun makes but never wears. Yes, spray tan or tanning salons.  Many people vacation somewhere cooler when it get's too hot.  Great Job overall.

Comment: Hulls or holes?

Answer (score 2):

My first thought would be:

> Water

Why:

> Something about blue and cold... And you can buy it in shops even it is free. Some will travel to it, other will want to avoid it

Comment: no, nice try though